# Shipping address layout

Tags: forms, e-commerce, addresses

Is there any layout recommended for shipping/mailing addresses for an ecommerce website? Currently I have all the shipping addresses out on 1 page along with the account details of the user, which makes the page very long. Even though I seperate account details and shipping addresses on different pages, one user can have up to quite a number of shipping/mailing addresses which makes the page long as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Amazon has the e-commerce experience down to a science.  I know this might sound trite but analyze them and don't be afraid to get ideas and even copy their structure where you think it might be appropriate. Not everything Amazon does will be the right solution for you but much of it will.

Comment: Amazon is good to copy. Apple has also created a fairly streamlined check out process as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds as if you are asking us to do your work for you when you haven't even given an example mock-up of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing more irritating if something goes wrong (temp 404, WiFi blips out etc) and you lose all the address info and card info at the same time. Saving it as you go as well means if someone doesn't complete a sale you can send an automatic email to them asking them if they would like to complete.

You will find a huge number of people don't complete if the first page is overloaded with requests, treat customers gently ask them for small amount of info at a time (general rule of mine - they should have have to scroll down the page on a checkout page).

[This post](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/06/fundamental-guidelines-of-e-commerce-checkout-design/) is very definitely worth a read, covers all aspects of making sure users complete; and that they come back in the future!